# How can I determine if there is a effect relation between variables if the cause is delayed with respect to the efect?

Tags: regression, prediction

I have a dataset from a process in which one of the variables codifies an event that I want to explain using the rest of the dataset. The problem is that the relation of the variables with the event happened some time in the past.

For example, a high value of a variable can cause the event, but this event occurs some unknown time later.

What kind of analysis may I apply to detect this relationships and to discover what is the delay in the cause-effect?

Thanks in advance